# Android: How to make two checkboxes in a single checkbox veiw

Tags: android, checkbox

i need a checkbox in a linerlayout that'll look like this:

```
Item1 [][]
Item2 [][]
Item3 [][]
```

and so on, how do i add another box to check in this?

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:button="@null"
                android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
                android:text="S-" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

im making it so that it'll have three choices, either the left can be ticked, the right can, or neither

Comment: What have you tried so far? What you are asking to do is pretty simple, provided you atleast read the basics of creating a view and using it in an activity.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add it to the layout and make the orientation horizontal:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:button="@null"
                android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
                android:text="S-" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:button="@null"
                android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
                android:text="" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Probably best to use a radio button though. Checkboxes imply that multiple items can be selected at one time. Your descriptions seems to imply that only one checkbox can be selected at a time.

Comment: i did say that you don't have to select either, which you cannot do with a radio button without making a third one for that matter